# How to create project for openshift next-gen on SpringToolSuite

Tags: spring, openshift, spring-tool-suite

I don't know how to create OpenShift Next-Gen project on Spring tool suite. for Openshift V2 I can create normally on my spring tool suite, and when I try to create the project for Openshift V3. It occurs errors. And I already search many times, and don't have any tutorial to create Openshift v3 Project on SpringToolSuite although the openshift is include on STS project.

Anybody help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of blog posts about using Spring and OpenShift which pop up when searching are:

- https://blog.openshift.com/using-spring-boot-on-openshift/
- https://blog.openshift.com/using-openshift-enterprise-grade-spring-boot-deployments/

Comment: yeah, your post is help me, but you didn't read clearly what I ask. That I want to use spring tool suite create directly openshift-next-gen project on my spring tool suite. Don't need to use any command or something like that. Which v2 account of openshift, I can create project directly on my spring tool suite and don't need to go to website and create anything on there. But I don't know how to do the same thing like that on Openshift-next-gen.